# Как передать переменную в Action из функции ? (Redux)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Идея простая:

В компонент из Store приходит массив категорий, из которого формируется набор ссылок. При клики по ссылке вызывается функция setCategoryWorks, которая обновляет state компонента.
А дальше, по идее, нужно передать state в action, чтобы обновить сам Store. И именно это не получается сделать. Подскажите, что я делаю не так, и как исправить?

**works.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import FilterItems from './elements/filter_items';
import { AppActions } from '../../actions/appActions';

interface IPortfolioProps {
  Works: any;
  СategoryList: any;
  Category: any;
  getWorks: () => void;
}
interface IPortfolioProps {}

class Portfolio extends React.Component<IPortfolioProps, IPortfolioState> {
constructor() {
 super();
}
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.getWorks();
}
setCategoryWorks = (elem:any) => {
  this.setState({
    Category: elem.target.textContent
  });
}
render() {
  let newWorks: any = this.props.Works;
  let CategoryList: any = this.props.СategoryList;
  let setCategory: any = this.props.Category;

return (
<div className="works-wrap">
  { 
  CategoryList.map((el:string, i:string) => {
  return <FilterItems
    key={i}
    category={el}
    setCategory={setCategory}
    setCategoryWorks={this.setCategoryWorks.bind(this)}
    />})
  }        
</div>
);
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any, ownProps: any) => {
return {
  Works: state.worksReducer.worksState,
  СategoryList: state.worksReducer.categoryList,
  Category: state.worksReducer.Category
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any, ownProps: any) => {
return {
  getWorks: () => { dispatch(AppActions.getWorks()); },
  setCategoryWorks: (Category:string) => { 
    dispatch(AppActions.setCategoryWork(Category)); },
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Portfolio));
```

**filter_items.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

interface IFilterItemsProps {
  category: string;
  setCategory: string;
  setCategoryWorks: (newCategoryName:string) => void;
}
interface IFilterItemsState {}

class FilterItems extends React.Component<IFilterItemsProps, IFilterItemsState> {
constructor(props:any) {
  super(props);
}
render() {
    const Category: any = this.props.category;
    const SetCategory: string = this.props.setCategory
    let ClassName: string = 'light';
    if(SetCategory == Category) {ClassName = 'light--active';}

    return (
      <a 
        onClick={ (event:any) => this.props.setCategoryWorks(event) }
        className={ ClassName }
      >
        {Category} </a>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any, ownProps: any) => {
  return {/* тут пусто */};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any, ownProps: any) => {
  return {/* тут пусто */};
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FilterItems));
```

Comment: стейт меняет не actionCreator, он же action, а reducer, который принимает action и текущий state и возвращает новое состояние приложения

Comment: как вы верно заметили, reducer принимает action, соответственно в action нужно передать значение, в чем и была задача. Но я разобрался что не работало, вопрос можно закрывать. Вы знаете как это сделать?